# Jenkins API tree filter using regex?

Tags: json, jenkins, hudson

I'm using the tree parameter to filter JSON data coming back from the API and that works great. My issue is I need to fetch some specific data from an array with a bunch of stuff I don't care about. I'm wondering if there is a way, using the tree command, to filter using a regex or contains string?

For example, to give me back all fileNames that start with MyProject:

```
   http://myapi.com?tree=fileName=MyProject*
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are great for regular grammars.

Trees tend to follow [context free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).  You might do a lot better with a language that can support context aware operations, like **XPath**.  Yes, a few very simple items might work without the extra features of **XPath**; however, once you do step on a use case that is beyond what is possible with regular grammars (they only support a small subset of what can be searched), it is literally impossible to accomplish the search with the tool in hand.

If you care to see how regular grammars tend to come with limitations, study [the pumping lemma](http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node18.html), and then think deeply about it's implications.  [A quick brush-up on parsing theory might also be useful](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp06/lectures/lecture05introparse-6.pdf).  You are up against mathematics, including the parts of mathematics which include logical operations.  It's not a matter of being a difficult problem to solve, it has been proven that regular expressions cannot match context free grammars.

If you are just more interested in getting the job done quickly. I suggest you start off by reading up on [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and try to leverage one of the already available tools, or at least use it as a guide in your tree matching efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using not using the JSON and instead switching to XML you can filter with XPATH. An example on finding all job urls with name starting with "Test" is this:

```
https://{jenkins_instance_url}/view/All/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url]&xpath=/*/job[starts-with(name,'Test')]/url&wrapper=jobs
```